How to remove default pagebuilder elements
I have made some custom content types for the Magento 2 Page Builder, and now need to remove some of the default ones (eg. everything under the Elements dropdown) to prevent them from being used.
I'm guessing it's removed through XML however I can't find any information on how to achieve this. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Create a folder structure as given below

Create app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/registration.php
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Tarun_StackOverflow', __DIR__);


Create app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/etc/module.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Tarun_StackOverflow" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_PageBuilder"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>

Create app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/etc/di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Config\CompositeReader">
        <plugin name="removePageBuilderElementsFromMenuSection" type="Tarun\StackOverflow\Model\Plugin\Config\RemoveElementsMenu" />
    </type>
</config>

Create app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/Model/Plugin/Config/RemoveElementsMenu.php
<?php


namespace Tarun\StackOverflow\Model\Plugin\Config;


use Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Config\CompositeReader;

class RemoveElementsMenu
{
    const MENU_TO_REMOVE = [
        'button-item',
        'buttons',
        'text',
        'heading',
        'divider',
        'html'
    ];
    public function afterRead(
        CompositeReader $subject,
        array $result,
        $scope = null
    ) {
        foreach (self::MENU_TO_REMOVE as $menuToRemove) {
            if (isset($result['types'][$menuToRemove])) {
                unset($result['types'][$menuToRemove]);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

You can update the constant array elements as per your requirement.
If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.
Happy Coding

@rich please let me know if you are looking for this solution or if I have misunderstood it. If it works for you then please mark it as accepted. You can update the array as per your requirement to remove or add elements as per your need.

Great, yep that works. Many thanks indeed

Thank you @rich, for appreciating.

To remove default elements, you must identify them in the core file.
Follow the below steps.

Create Vendor_Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml file.
Set 'componentDisabled' to 'true'.

Example:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="content" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <!-- Use 'remove' to remove specific elements -->
                        <item name="accordion" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </fieldset>
</form>


The above code will disable the accordion element from the page builder.

@rich
Hey,
Identify the Modules to Disable:
PageBuilder elements are provided by various modules. Some common PageBuilder modules include:
Magento_PageBuilder
Magento_PageBuilderDataMigration
Magento_PageBuilderAnalytics
Magento_PageBuilderAdminGws
Magento_PageBuilderGraphQl

Disable the Modules:
To disable a module, you can use the Magento CLI command. Open your terminal and run the following commands:
bin/magento module:disable Magento_PageBuilder
bin/magento module:disable Magento_PageBuilderDataMigration
bin/magento module:disable Magento_PageBuilderAnalytics
bin/magento module:disable Magento_PageBuilderAdminGws
bin/magento module:disable Magento_PageBuilderGraphQl

Update the Database:
After disabling the modules, you need to run the setup upgrade command to update the database:
bin/magento setup:upgrade

Clear the Cache:
Finally, clear the Magento cache to ensure all changes are applied:
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush

Thank You!

That's not what I'm looking for, that removes modules, I need to remove elements from the page builder, not disable the modules totally.
